# Direct product and inverse element of Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $(P_2[\mathbb{R}],+)$ and $(\text{GL}(2,\mathbb R), \cdot)$ be groups. How can I write direct product G of those groups. Let 
$a = \left (2x^2+4x-3,\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1\\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right)$ and 
$b= \left (-x^2+x-1, \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right ).$ Find id element in G, a*b and a^-1.

solution:

So far I have done following:

i) id element in G

$$
\left (0, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right )
$$

ii)

$$ a*b= \left (x^2+5x-4, \begin{pmatrix}7 & -3 \\ 5 & -2 \end{pmatrix} \right )$$

***Is this the same thing as direct product or I need to do some different steps?***

iii)

$$ \left (x^2-x+1, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \right) $$

Am I on right way to do this, and is a*b same thing as direct product?

thanks in advance

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: @AnuragA  First of all thanks! What's abbout direct product, is it same as a*b or I need to do something else? I found in one book that it needs to be written as set without doing any operations but in another paper that it is exactly a * b. So I am a bit confused now

Comment: If you have groups $(G, \star)$ and $(H, \circ)$, then their direct product is the set $G \times H=\{(a,b) \, | \, a\in G \text{ and } b \in H\}$. Now this set has a group operation $\times$ which it inherits from the component groups $G$ and $H$. So we can define$$(a_1, b_1) \times (a_2, b_2)=(a_1 \star a_2, b_1 \circ b_2).$$

Comment: @AnuragA so for my example I can write it (direct product) as  ((2x^2+4x-3)+ (-x^2+x-1),{{3 1}{2 1}} · {{2 -1}{1 0}})? and the part from ii) a * b =..etc is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exactly the right idea!

Given two groups $(G,\star)$ and $(H, \cdot)$ we can form their **Direct Product** $G \times H$ whose elements are pairs $(g,h)$ with $g \in G$ and $h \in H$.

Now this object is a group "componentwise" in the following sense:

- $\text{Id}_{G \times H} = (\text{Id}_G, \text{Id}_H)$
- $(g_1,h_1)(g_2,h_2) = (g_1 \star g_2, h_1 \cdot h_2)$
- $(g,h)^{-1} = (g^{-1}, h^{-1})$

In your case, you correctly identified that, for $G = P_2[\mathbb R]$ and $H = \text{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ this means:

- the identity element is $(\text{Id}_G, \text{Id}_H) = 
  \left ( 0 + 0x + 0x^2, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right )$
- the product $ab$ is $\left ( (2x^2 + 4x - 3) + (-x^2 + x - 1), 
  \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1\\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right )$
- the inverse $a^{-1} = \left ( 2x^2 + 4x - 3, \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right )^{-1}$ is $\left ( - (2x^2 + 4x - 3), \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \right )$

Notice, in particular, that we write the "inverse" of a polynomial $p$ as $-p$, while we write the inverse of a matrix $A$ as $A^{-1}$. This is because we write the operation on the matrix group as multiplication, but we write polynomial group operation as addition.

As a final remark, you seem to have accidentally taken $b^{-1}$ for part iii. Conceptually, though, your idea is correct.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Helped a lot actually! I was just very confused for direct product if I need do do calculation or just to leave it as you wrote "in the product ab is ". Now I have idea and think I know the difference. Thanks a lot and cheers! 